# Object with dynamic attribute in fortran

Tags: oop, dynamic, memory-leaks, fortran

I am programming in Fortran and I need to create an object class that has a dynamic vector as an attribute. Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
MODULE my_class
        PRIVATE
        PUBLIC my_object

        ! define my object with a dynamic attribute
        TYPE my_object
                private
                integer:: size;
                real, allocatable:: tab(:); ! here the dynamic vector
        CONTAINS
                private
                final:: destructor;
        END TYPE my_object

        ! define an interface for object constructor
        INTERFACE my_object
                module procedure:: constructor;
        END INTERFACE my_object

CONTAINS

        ! define constructor
        FUNCTION constructor(size) RESULT(obj)
                integer, intent(in):: size;
                type(my_object):: obj;

                obj%size= size;
                allocate(obj%tab(size))
        END FUNCTION constructor

        ! define destructor
        SUBROUTINE destructor(this)
                class(my_object):: this;

                if (allocated(this%tab)) deallocate(this%tab)
        END SUBROUTINE
END MODULE my_class
```

But I am not sure that is the proper way to do it. Is there not a risk of memory leaking with this implementation in case of multiple initializations? With this code for example :

```
PROGRAM test
        USE my_class
        IMPLICIT NONE
        type(my_object):: obj;

        obj= my_object(1000);
        obj= my_object(3000);
END PROGRAM test
```

Has the `obj%tab` of the first instance been properly deallocated?
Or should I reimplement the equal operator?

Thanks for helping me to find out how Fortran deals with this.

Comment: Firstly note your example is incorrect and won't compile - it should be `type( my_object )` in the finalisation routine `destructor`. But otherwise yes, at the second assignment it will be properly deallocated  before the new value is assigned to `obj` - essentially as long as you stick to allocatable arrays you can't get a memory leak in Fortran. There is no need to implement the assignment operator here. There must be a duplicate somewhere but no time to search.

Comment: By the standard, everything should be deallocated automatically and there shouldn't be memory leaks. But note that there are several extant compiler bugs in this area, so you might get memory leaks where you shouldn't, depending on what you want to do.